# Copying a single field item from a list to a related task list using SPD workflows

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm really new to Sharepoint 2010 and was wondering if it is possible to copy a single field from an item in a list to a related task?

Basically I have a holiday request list that triggers an approval task list, and in that task list I would like to copy over a field from the related holiday request list item.

e.g my user enters details into a form, clicks ok and then a task is created for approval, but some info from the list is usable in the task for display on the form.

I'm not sure if this is possible in SPD, or if I would have to delve deeper using Visual Studio. Any comments and advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Kev,

[Assuming you have SharePoint Server 2010]

This is easily possible with SPD, on [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx?CTT=1) - have a look at:
Opening the approval workflows in SharePoint Designer 2010

So you have an activity called Start Approval Workflow - which gives you the Task Item's reference in Workflow Variables and then you can use action Update List Item to update the task item and set it to your current item's desired field...

[Workflow actions in SharePoint Designer 2010: A quick reference guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx?CTT=1)

Please let me know if you need more help!